# using ng-options on object with duplicate values - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

[JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/jobojuza/1/edit?html,js,output)

I'm using an object for my `ng-options` :

```
$scope.data = {
    option1 : 1,
    option2 : 1,
    option3 : 1,
    option4 : 2 
  };
```

Notice that options 1-3 has the same value `1`

Using this `select` element with the `ng-options` directive

```
<select   ng-model=combo_value 
          ng-change='set_value()'
          ng-options="k for (k,v) in data">
</select>
```

I'm unable to select options 1 and 2.

Even weirder is that using the keyboard i can select options 1 & 2 but when selecting with the mouse, the select is automatically jumping to option 3 (guessing that it's because it's the last option with the value `1`).

I tried different `ng-options` expression but none seem to work

```
v as k for (k,v) in data
k for (k,v) in data track by $index
k for (k,v) in data track by k
```

*note : `k` is always unique*

Answer (score 0):

```
k as v for (k, v) in data
```

should let you select any option. In this case your model `combo_value` will get the value *option1*, *option2*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-options="k as k for (k,v) in data"` to show and get *option1*, *option2*, *option3*, *option4* as selected value.

Here the working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/S8RBm8?p=preview